# solr: Filter while indexing

Tags: indexing, solr, filter, lucene

I've written a custom filter that if a token contains "http" then the token will be replaced with string "lucene".

[check schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72fd1.png)

so "http" becomes "lucene"

after indexing  I searched "lucene" and got the document, but the thing is I'm also getting the same document when I searched "http".

[check Analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jeycn.png)

Can you please explain why? (I think in index there will be only "lucene" that maps the document but not "http".)

Thank you!

Comment: What does the analysis page show for indexing and querying? Could be that you're reversing on query as well, meaning that HTTP gets revered to ptth when you're querying the field as well. You can change this by providing separate analysis steps for indexing and querying.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've edited my question presenting all details. please consider explaining it.

Comment: Have you reindexed / cleaned the index after changing the analysis chain? The analysis example doesn't show a hit for any of the tokens.

Comment: thank you! reindexing  worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you reindexed / cleaned the index after changing the analysis chain? The analysis example doesn't show a hit for any of the tokens.

Remember that the tokens stored doesn't change unless you reindex the content, even if you change the analysis chain.